# Is there an equivalent to get() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a sequence of messages in json and they include a field called `part`, which is an integer from 0 to 2. I have three message queues and the value of `part` determines which queue I send the message over to.

This is my current code.

```
output0 = queue.Queue()
output1 = queue.Queue()
output2 = queue.Queue()

json = json.loads('{"test": "message", "part": "2"}')
part = int(json["part"])

if part == 0:
    output0.put(json)

elif part == 1:
    output1.put(json)

elif part == 2:
    output2.put(json)
```

I'd like to simplify it with something like.

```
chooseQueue = "output" + str(json["part"])
chooseQueue.put(json)
```

It serves me this error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'put'`

In R, I can use a string as a variable name by using `as.formula()` or `get()`.

Comment: btw you are overwriting name `json`, use a different name for a `load`ed object, e.g. `payload`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to your question is `locals()`.

The answer to you problem is a `dict`

```
queue_dict = {'1': queue.Queue(), '2': queue.Queue(), '3': queue.Queue()}
queue = queue_dict[json["part"]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You *can*, but you'd be much better off keeping your queues in a dict:

```py
queues = {"output0": queue.Queue(),
          "output1": queue.Queue(),
          "output2": queue.Queue(),
         }
chooseQueue = "output" + str(json["part"])
queues[chooseQueue].put(json)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `locals()` function to access variables in the local scope by name:

```
chooseQueue = locals()["output" + str(json["part"])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers tell you that you should use the built-in `locals()` function, and while they are right, I'd like to notify you of the `globals()` function which returns a dictionary of global variables, which you create using the `global` keyword.

For example, in a Python 3 terminal the `globals()` function returns:

```
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>}
```

Good luck.